# How to get a full 3 last days report from jenkins (without adding/modifying plugins)?

Tags: bash, batch-file, jenkins, report

How to get a full 3 last days report from jenkins (*without adding/modifying plugins*) ?

restrictions :

- In fact I'm not allowed to add new plugins to the jenkins system we
  use.
- I m not allowed for financial reasons to ask a new script for
  each pipeline

But my goal was to get a 3 last days reports, listing all of the pipelines triggered & their ok/failed status, whatever the runner host was.

I can't find any documented method for that. I tryied to use the WebUI server /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log file to extract things but I failed to get something pertinent.

how can I do that ? is it at least possible (*with my restrictions*) ?
what method can I use for this ?

Comment: What kind of rest api's are available on your jenkins server? You can check that in your url <https://yourjenkinsurl.com/api>. Based on what is available (XML, JSON, Python) you can fetch the things you desire and build your own (custom) report. On every job, build you can (almost anytime) access the data you are looking for.

Comment: looks like xml & json are available ; thanks. but how can I get that from cli ?

Comment: From jenkins cli? I do not have experience with that unfortunately. I just use jenkins rest-api on project & builds (via python, curl, wget, etc) to collect the relevant data. Some documentation, wrappers and examples can be found here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/ and here (comments) https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API/. There's also an answer here with a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31585822/8195106. Hope this helps